# PhpUnit + Symfony: Why coverage shows white instead of red and gives 100% on untested class?

Tags: symfony, phpunit, code-coverage, function-coverage

I have a problem and I have created an empty project to reproduce the minimal situation that makes it repeatable.

## Problem

A project with untested classes gives 100% coverage. The problematic methods are **not** indirectly called from somewhere else. Although there are other methods of the untested class that are indirectly called when testing another class.

## How to reproduce

### Step 1: Create an empty new symfony project.

- I have created a new symfony 3.3 project with this command: `symfony new coverage_trial_to_be_deleted`

**Result:** If I run `vendor/bin/simple-phpunit --coverage-html coverageReport` I get a fully tested project, as expected, as the sample contains one default test for one default controller.

### Step 2: Delete the controller and create two commands, but do not cover them.

- I then eliminate the controller by removing the full `src/Controller` directory, the test for the controller, and the references to that directroy in the app configuration.
- I then create a `src/Command` directory with 2 commands: `DummyACommand.php` and `DummyBCommand.php`.
- I then create a stupid test that performs an `assertTrue( true );` to have something to report, but does not invoke the commands at all.

**Result:** This works correct. It then reports 0% on the `Command` directory, like this:

[image: Result of all Command section]

In particular, inside the `Command` I can see the 2 commands at 0%, which is normal:

[image: Commands at 0%]

And finally if I enter the second of the commands, the "B" command, say `DummyBCommand`, I can still see that neither the `configure()` nor the `execute()` methods have been covered, and I see, as expected, a red area on each of those methods:

[image: Report of Command B]

Up to here, everything works as expected.

### Step 3: Add test for command A only and do NOT test command B.

I then add a new test, named `DummyACommandTest.php` with the following content:

```
<?php

declare( strict_types=1 );

namespace Tests\AppBundle\Command;

use AppBundle\Command\DummyACommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Tester\CommandTester;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;

class EnvironmentListCommandTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    public function testExecute()
    {
        $kernel = $this->createKernel();
        $kernel->boot();

        $application = new Application( $kernel );
        $application->add( new DummyACommand() );

        $command = $application->find( 'dummy:a' );
        $commandTester = new CommandTester( $command );
        $commandTester->execute(
            [
                'command' => $command->getName(),
            ]
        );

        $output = $commandTester->getDisplay();
        $this->assertContains( 'dummy A command', $output );
    }
}
```

The test gives green light, as expected, as it invokes the DummyACommand and executes it, then it checks for the output and it really contains what it is expected:

[image: Tests pass with green light]

It says 2 tests because the `assertTrue( true );` is still there.

**Result:** Now, if I look at the coverage of DummyBCommand I should see the `configure()` method covered, because the fact of testing A invokes a `$application->find( 'dummy:a' );` and I guess it explores all the commands.

I really don't understand this very much, as I only do the `$application->add( new DummyACommand() );` and I don't know when `dummy:b` is loaded, but anyway let's give this hypothesis a chance.

So I don't mind seeing the `configure()` in green (Annotation `[1]` in the following image).

But what I don't like is that then, the `execute()` of B instead of appearing in red (noone calls that execution, should appear exactly as in step 2), it appears in white!!! :| like in annotation `[2]` here:

[image: Now command 2 has a white section instead of red section]

So for some reason... testing Command A makes the PHPUnit to change its consideration of what is "potentially executable" in Command B and I don't understand why.

This makes the full project to be reported as 100% tested, while it is false, like in here:

[image: Full report shows a false coverage indication]

but of course this information does not reflect the reality: the `execute()` method of the command B is not covered and never executed.

I'd hope that the report tells me 75% line coverage (3 of 4) and 50% class coverage (1 of 2).

## So... Question:

Why does PhpUnit change its consideration about what is potentially executable code in class B while adding a test for class A?

How can I instruct PhpUnit to see B as uncovered?

Thanks!
Xavi.

Comment: It seems this question is related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40183931/why-wont-phpunit-code-coverage-report-functions-that-arent-called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found!!

## Quick solution

Update the `xdebug` library here: https://xdebug.org/wizard.php

## Detailed solution

As you can see in the question's images, I was using the `Xdebug 2.4.0` because that's the one that just was in my system, a stable `Ubuntu 16.04`.

As per this thread: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/issues/411 during one full year those folks (thanks you all) they were pursuing the same problem: Lines not being reported as executable.

Finally they came to the conclusion that there was a bug in `XDebug` and it finally was reported and corrected.

This is: xdebug was improerply reporting data to phpunit, so phpunit was running on erroneous hypothesis.

I upgraded here https://xdebug.org/wizard.php (the link I found in that thread), and I compiled a new `xdebug` as instructed.

Here you can see that the project is not now 100%, but 75% in lines and 50% in classes (as expected):

[image]

Here you can see that the Command A reports 100% (which is okey, because it is the one I test) and Command B is reported 50% in lines and 0% in class, as expected, as I did not write a test for it. The method `configure()` is run on kernel boot and application loading:

[image]

And if we enter in Command B (ie: `DummyBCommand`) we can finally see that the method `execute()` is marked as red, not white:

[image]

In this image you can see in `[1]` that the `configure()` is 100% and the `execute()` is 0%, which is correct.

In `[2]` you can see the colors. `execute()` is marked red, as expected.

And finally, in `[3]` you can see that the XDebug version is the `2.5.4`, the latest stable on 10/sep/2017 (or at least, the one that the update wizard suggested me to install).

So... download, configure, compile, install and boom, done!