# PHPUnit is effectively marking an untested class (0% coverage) as being covered

Tags: php, phpunit, code-coverage

PHPUnit is marking some classes that don't have test coverage as "n/a" but the result is that the code coverage percentage is inflated, as their lines aren't being counted.

These classes are uncovered so I would like them treated as so.

How do I achieve this?

PHPUnit Configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="tests/bootstrap.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false"
         syntaxCheck="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./src</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <logging>
        <log type="coverage-html"
             target="./tests/log/report"
             charset="UTF-8"
             yui="true"
             hightlight="true"
             lowupperbound="50"
             highlowerbound="80" />
    </logging>
</phpunit>
```

Output:

[image]

The EventApi class has 3 methods and 40 lines.

Comment: Annotations can ignore classes https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html#code-coverage-analysis.ignoring-code-blocks

Comment: I'm not using any in that class.

Comment: You'd probably need to manually exclude such files within an `<exclude>` block in the `<filter><whitelist>` section, as currently they will be picked up as part of the LOC to measure with.

Comment: I don't want to exclude it - I'm trying to get it to be included.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but can you try following filters?

```
   <whitelist>
            <directory>./src</directory>
        </whitelist>
```

see here [Phpunit coverage: what is the difference between 'addUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist' and 'processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist' options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041254/phpunit-coverage-what-is-the-difference-between-adduncoveredfilesfromwhitelist#29042391)

Answer (score -1):

`PHP_CodeCoverage` based on the `xdebug`/`phpdbg`, it can only track actually executed lines of code and they don't know from what test case caused this execution. If this classes used in another tests and you don't mock them, then PHPUnit considers them as covered. If this classes used in another tests and you don't mock them, then PHPUnit considers them as covered.

From the [manual](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html):

> PHP_CodeCoverage only considers a function or method as covered when all of its executable lines are covered. 
>   PHP_CodeCoverage only considers a class or trait as covered when all of its methods are covered.

So even without any direct tests for class, it may be marked as covered. If you need to test only one class without affecting others code, then you need to mock each other. But it may be hard when using static methods, global functions, etc.

Also, you can use [`@cover`](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/code-coverage-analysis.html#code-coverage-analysis.specifying-covered-methods):

> ### Specifying Covered Methods
>
> The `@covers` annotation (see Table B.1) can be used in the test code to specify which method(s) a test method wants to test. If provided, only the code coverage information for the specified method(s) will be considered.

Comment: Has the behaviour changed between versions? I'm sure it used to add unexecuted code by virtue of `syntaxCheck="true"`?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not sure. Also, `@cover` annotation may be useful.

Comment: This is the exact opposite of what the question relates to. The question relates to untested files not being included in the code coverage percentage, which makes it very difficult to find untested files or methods that have just been added.